# Java Menu Mnemonics in Resource Files

Tags: java, internationalization

I would like to assign a mnemonic to a `JMenu` using resource bundles (or the `ResourceMap`). So for example, the code without resource file would be...

```
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu();
fileMenu.setText("File");   // this would be read from a resource file
fileMenu.setMnemonic('F');  // but the docs say this is obsolete
fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
```

So how do I put the KeyEvent.VK_F in a resource file?

For a `JMenuItem` I can do it with actions, but this is `JMenu`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java's [javax.swing.KeyStroke](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html) class bridges the gap:

```
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu();
String mnemonic = // string from localization
fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(mnemonic).getKeyCode());
```

Accelerators are not supported for `JMenu`s, only for `JMenuItem`s (which makes sense, since these invoke an action without using the menu at all).

Answer (score 1):

Inside the resource file use the accelerator

add.Action.accelerator = control A

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a similar way, and treat "FileMenu" as a (fake) action?